# Ember DS.Store.findAll() returns empty collection

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

Hey I need to modify some records which I get from the DataStore. If I add the following code in my router I can see that the requests get passed to my template, but I can't modify each request of the collection because the collection is empty.

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('user').then(function(users) {
    console.log(users.get('length')); // 0
    return users;
  });
}
```

I thought that the promise gets resolved when all the records have been fetched from the server but this doesn't seem to be the case. Or did I completely miss something.

I also tried to modify the model in the afterModel callback with the same result.

I'm using Ember 1.13.0 (with Ember-CLI), Ember-Data 1.13.4 and ember-cli-mirage for Mocking my HTTP Requests.

**UPDATE:**
I managed to create a workaround for this issue. In my controller, I created a new property which listens for model.@each and then I was able to modify model and pass it to the view.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  users: function() {
    return this.get('model.users').filter(function(user) {
      // The Promise is resolved twice
      // The first time with an empty model and the second time with 
      // the actual data. So I filter the empty model. 
      return user.get('id');
    }).map(function(user) {
      // do fancy stuff with our user
      return user
    });
  }.property('model.@each')
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ember Data 1.13**

So after spending some time on this topic i found the solution to this issue. It's basically the way how ember works. So under the hood findAll is returning two promises.

**findAll without data in the store**

- find records from the store (resolve first promise -> length 0,
  because no data is in the store)
- fetch new data in the background (resolves second promise)

**findAll with data in the store**

- find records from the store (resolve first promise with cached data)
- fetch new data in the background (resolves second promise with new
  data)

If you want to wait for all the data to be loaded you can use query which is returning only one promise.

```
model() {
  return this.store.query('user', {});
}
```

For findRecord I found the following workaround, which is only working if your backend supports any kind of filtering on the id of your record.

```
model() {
  return this.store.query('user', {
    'filter[id]': 1
  }).then((users) => {
    return users.objectAt(0);
  });
}
```

You can have a look on the following discussion on [github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3657)

**Ember Data 2.0**

On Ember Data 2.0 this issue is resolved.

Comment: Could you specify how this behaviour could be useful?

Comment: I had two endpoints with no relation between them and I had to combine both of the record collections in the afterModel hook. There is also a discussion on github https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3657 where people are confused about this behaviour. As it seems the issue is resolved with Ember Data 2.0 so I'll update my answer that this only happens on 1.13

Comment: Oh ok I thought findAll was acting like this by design, and wanted to know why :P

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure the data is coming in from Mirage as you expect. Open your Ember inspector and verify the models made it into your store. If not, you likely have a problem with the format of the JSON response from your mock route.

To diagnose, check out your console for a log of the JSON response, and ensure it matches what you expect. If you have a custom route handler in your `/mirage/config.js` for this route, you could also put a `debugger` statement in there and verify the data is what you think it should be.

If you're using default Ember Data 1.13, it probably means you're using the JSON API serializer/adapter. Is this what you intend? What is the backend for this app ultimately going to look like? If it's going to be JSON API, you'll need to do a bit more work in the Mirage `config.js` file for now, something like

```
this.get('/contacts', function(db, request) {
  return {
    data: db.contacts.map(attrs => {
      type: 'contacts',
      id: attrs.id,
      attributes: attrs
    })
  };
});
```

Comment: I checked the response and things get loaded into the store correctly. We wrote a custom serializer which converts mirage factories into jsonAPI responses. The funny thing is that I can access the models when I listen to .property('users.@each') in my controller and then do this.get('users').forEach(). So I think that there might be a bug with the promise which doesn't add the records to the users parameter.

Comment: gotcha, then it's not a problem in the mirage->ED layer. have you overwritten setupController? are you accessing {{model}} in your template?

Comment: No I didn't overwrite the setup controller but I can access the model in the template. So the records get displayed if I iterate over them in my view.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to the one you are describing when using Ember and Ember data version 1.13. At the time, I was reading the updated documentation of Ember 2.0 without Ember Data 2.0. Once I upgraded both libraries I was able to get the behavior you are trying to achieve with the first code snippet. Namely, the promise is handled correctly with nonzero records with ember data 2.0.